# Php: Nested for loop not working

Tags: php

This will work

```
$arrayOrdenado = array();
if ($rows[4][2] == $orden[0]) {
    array_push($arrayOrdenado,$rows[4]);
}
```

But while looping it won't find any coincidence

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $orden.length - 1; $i++) { 
    for ($y = 0; $y < $rows.length - 1; $y++) { 
        if ($rows[y][2] == $orden[i]) {
            array_push($arrayOrdenado, $rows[y]);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why

Comment: `$rows.length-1`/`$orden.length` is a javascript thing. `count($rows)`/`count($orden)` is php. In php the `.` is used for concatentation like `"a"."b"` is the same as `"ab"`. Your code would likely throw errors like `undefined constant, assumed length`.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question. What are you wanting to do?

Comment: I have an array ($orden) which cointains the IDs in order. I want to order the second array($rows) which contains arrays and the ID is the [2] value that's the $rows[y][2] has an static [2].

Comment: Turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL)`, you should be getting warnings.

Comment: Why are you subtracting 1 from `length`? That will ignore the last element in each array. Is that intentional?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use `foreach` to loop over arrays.

```
foreach (array_slice($orden, 0, -1) as $o) {
    foreach (array_slice($rows, 0, -1) as $row) {
        if ($row[2] == $o) {
            $arrayOrdenado[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

Another way to write this is:

```
foreach (array_slice($rows, 0, -1) as $row) {
    if (in_array($row[2], array_slice($orden, 0, -1)) {
        $arrayOrdenado[] = $row;
    }
}
```

I'm using `array_slice()` to match the behavior of using `length-1` in your original `for` loops, which ignores the last element of the arrays. I would actually move that out to a variable so it doesn't have to do it every time through the outer loop, but I left it that way in the code above to keep it shorter.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the `$` characters:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($orden)-1; $i++) { 
      for ($y=0; $y < count($rows)-1; $y++) { 
        if($rows[$y][2]==$orden[$i]){
          array_push($arrayOrdenado,$rows[$y]);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Ive been doing too much javascript lately.. This plus Jonathan's answer resolved my problem

Comment: Also, how would I implement a counter like $i and $y in a foreach loop?

Comment: Great to see it helped, using multiple languages can be confusing sometimes

Comment: Instead of $orden.length you should use count($orden)

Comment: So `$ordenkey` would be the new `$i`

Comment: This answer is not right. PHP doesn't use `.length`, that's Javascript.